# not able to convert this query into codeingiter query

Tags: codeigniter

i want this query to be converted in CodeIgniter format.

```
SELECT image.image_id, image.image_name, category_name, 
image.image_description, image.image, image.status, image.cdate, image.user_id 
FROM tbl_image as image 
left join tbl_imagecat category on image.category_id=category.category_id  
where ( 1 AND image.status = 0 AND image.user_id in (0,0)) ORDER BY image.image_id
```

Comment: Is there any code on what you have tried?

Comment: This is what i tried so far


$this->db->select('image.image_id, image.image_name, category_name, image.image_description, image.image, image.status, image.cdate, image.user_id');
           $this->db->from('tbl_image as image');
           $this->db->join('tbl_imagecat category on image.category_id=category.category_id','left');
           $this->db->where('( 1 AND image.status = 0 AND image.user_id in (0,0))');
           $this->db->order_by('image.image_id desc LIMIT 0, 10');

Comment: and its producing query like this 
-> SELECT `image`.`image_id`, `image`.`image_name`, `category_name`, `image`.`image_description`, `image`.`image`, `image`.`status`, `image`.`cdate`, `image`.`user_id` FROM `tbl_image` as `image` JOIN `tbl_imagecat category on` `image`.`category_id=category`.`category_id` USING (`left`) WHERE ( 1 AND `image`.`status` =0 AND `image`.`user_id` in (0,0)) ORDER BY `image`.`image_id desc LIMIT` 0, 10, `category_id` DESC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 4):

```
$this->db->select("image.image_id, image.image_name, category_name, image.image_description, image.image, image.status, image.cdate, image.user_id");
$this->db->from("tbl_image as image");
$this->db->join("tbl_imagecat category", "image.category_id=category.category_id", "LEFT");
$this->db->where("image.status", "0");
$this->db->where_in("image.user_id", array("0") );
$this->db->order_by("image.image_id");
```

Note : I just convert only query, I don't concern with your logic.

Comment: this query showing 



`Column 'category_id' in order clause is ambiguous`
and query is 
`SELECT `image`.`image_id`, `image`.`image_name`, `category_name`, `image`.`image_description`, `image`.`image`, `image`.`status`, `image`.`cdate`, `image`.`user_id` FROM `tbl_image` as `image` LEFT JOIN `tbl_imagecat` `category` ON `image`.`category_id`=`category`.`category_id` WHERE `image`.`status` = '0' AND `image`.`user_id` IN('0') ORDER BY `image`.`image_id`, `category_id` DESC LIMIT 10`

and i'm not able to figure out why :/

Comment: @YashGoswami In last you mention which table of category_id should be order by. For ex. image.category_id or category.category_id